# Need help determining why rails 3 app mailer is sending 2 emails instead of 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, actionmailer

### I am trying to testing sending email in my rails 3 app, and am testing with cucumber/rspec. In my test, I want the user to be able to receive an email, but instead of sending one, it is sending two. Here is my feature:

features/ticket_notications.feature

```
Feature: Ticket Notifications
Background:
Given there are the following users:
| email              | password |
| alice@ticketee.com | password |
| bob@ticketee.com   | password |

Given a clear email queue

Given there is a project called "TextMate 2"
And "alice@ticketee.com" can view the "TextMate 2" project
And "bob@ticketee.com" can view the "TextMate 2" project
And "alice@ticketee.com" has created a ticket for this project:
| title        | description       |
| Release date | TBA very shortly. |

Given I am signed in as "bob@ticketee.com"
Given I am on the homepage

Scenario: Ticket owner is automatically subscribed to a ticket
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  And I follow "Release date"
  And I fill in "Text" with "Is it out yet?"
  And I press "Create Comment"
  Then "alice@ticketee.com" should receive an email
  When "alice@ticketee.com" opens the email
  Then they should see "updated the Release date ticket" in the email body
  And they should see "[ticketee] TextMate 2 - Release date" in the email subject
  Then they click the first link in the email
  Then I should see "Release date" within "#ticket h2"
```

#### When I run this I get this error:

```
Then "alice@ticketee.com" should receive an email                               
  # features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:5
  expected: 1
  got: 2 (using ==)* (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb:52:in `/^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive (an|no|\d+) emails?$/'
  features\ticket_notifications.feature:26:in `Then "alice@ticketee.com" should receive an email'
```

So for some reason it' receiving two emails instead of one, as seen in this line
expected: 1
got: 2

Here is some more code:

app/observers/comment_observer

```
class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(comment)
    (comment.ticket.watchers - [comment.user]).each do |user|
   Notifier.comment_updated(comment, user).deliver
end
  end
end
```

app/models/ticket.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :watchers, :join_table => "ticket_watchers",
:class_name => "User"

after_create :creator_watches_me

private
  def creator_watches_me
    self.watchers << user
  end
```

app/config/application.rb

```
 config.active_record.observers = :comment_observer
```

app/mailers/notifier.rb

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
default from: "ticketee@gmail.com"

def comment_updated(comment, user)
@comment = comment
@user = user
mail(:to => user.email, 
     :subject => "[ticketee] #{comment.ticket.project.name} - #{comment.ticket.title}")
  end
end
```

**So, can anyone help me figure out why rspec reporting two emails instead of only one?**

Edit: The code for the failing step:

features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb

```
Then /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive (an|no|\d+) emails?$/ do |address, amount|
  unread_emails_for(address).size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end
```

**Edit 2:**
Here is the code from the log file

https://gist.github.com/2294406

Comment: What does the code for the step that is failing look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of it, I think we have the same problem. I'm following the same book (Rails 3 in Action) and got stuck in the same place. I couldn't detect where exactly the problem is, but when I put :

```
class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(comment)
    p comment.ticket.watchers
    (comment.ticket.watchers - [comment.user]).each do |user|
      Notifier.comment_updated(comment, user).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

I saw that the watchers array of comment object contains duplicate of the same user:

```
[#<User id: 1, email: "alice@ticketee.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$D27BhCTxcOqsidMSDhp0FebonA82npQ01iFib3zwYCfT...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", updated_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", confirmation_sent_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", admin: false>, #<User id: 1, email: "alice@ticketee.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$D27BhCTxcOqsidMSDhp0FebonA82npQ01iFib3zwYCfT...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", updated_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", confirmation_sent_at: "2012-07-02 15:32:42", admin: false>]
```

I dunno why, but I just created a workaround on this by putting an array of user id inside the  sending loop :

```
class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(comment)
    sent = []
    (comment.ticket.watchers - [comment.user]).each do |user|
      Notifier.comment_updated(comment, user).deliver unless sent.include?(user.id)
      sent << user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Dirty, but it worked. I'm hoping someone can figure out what happened here.

Comment: I think you can find the solution here. http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=47523

Comment: Better late then never! This is actually the point that I stopped working on that book and hopped to Rails 3 in Action, because I read on his twitter he is revising the book I decided to wait for that one. Maybe i'll pick it up again. Many thanks for taking the time. I switched the answer to yours since it is very specific to my problem

Comment: goodness, the book really has quite a number of errors...I even have to resolve a few that were on the errata itself o.o

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you have other observer / callback which is triggered in the given example.
Try to clear mail queue before step `And I press "Create Comment"`. In order to debug sending email you can use excellent https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher gem or just check application logs.

Comment: Ok I am looking at the application logs and I can see where it is sending the two emails, but I can't see why. I will post it in the answer to be reviewed.